# How can I have Sub Sum column in sql query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following table in Sqlite

```
Person1     Person2     Amount
A           X           1000
A           Y           2000
A           Z           5000
B           X           3000
B           Y           4000
```

how can I write a query to add an extra column that its value is the sum of Amount for each Person in Column Person1.

I need the following result:

```
Person1     Person2     Amount      SumAmountPerson1
A           X           1000        8000
A           Y           2000        8000
A           Z           5000        8000
B           X           3000        5000
B           Y           2000        5000
```

my query is:

```
select *, Sum(Amount) from MyTable 

GROUP by Person1
```

But it returns the following result set in Sqlite:

```
Person1     Person2     Amount      SumAmountPerson1
A           X           1000        8000
B           X           3000        5000
```

But I need all rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not support window functions, so one option to get your result would be to use a subquery to aggregate amounts by the first person, and then join this back to your original table.

```
SELECT t1.Person1,
       t1.Person2,
       t1.Amount,
       t2.SumAmountPerson1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Person1, SUM(Amount) AS SumAmountPerson1
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Person1
) t2
    ON t1.Person1 = t2.Person1
```